# SQL Server Comparing how many data matches, and only in one tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:
CustomerInformation

```
CustomerName CustomerAddress CustomerID LocationID   BillDate
CITY - 1    500 N ST    47672001    29890   2012-07-20 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - 1    500 N ST    47672001    29890   2012-07-20 00:00:00.000 6890
CITY - 1    500 N ST    47672001    29890   2012-08-17 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - 9    510 N ST    47643241    29890   2012-08-17 00:00:00.000 5460
CITY - 4213 500 S ST    43422001    29890   2012-09-17 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - 5    100 N ST    23272001    29890   2012-09-17 00:00:00.000 4940
CITY - 3    010 N ST    43323001    29890   2012-10-19 00:00:00.000 0
CITY - 78   310 N ST    12222001    29890   2012-10-19 00:00:00.000 5370
```

and CustomerMeters has three columns: ID, Name, Address

The connection between these two tables is: CustomerAddress, so I can join the two based on Address:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerInformation 
JOIN CustomerMeters 
ON CustomerAddress  = Address
```

Now, the problem is I have so many records (over 20000 in the CustomerInformation), Is there away that I list how many records that matches in both tables, and how many records are only in the CustomerInformation table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    C.grp, count(*)
from CustomerInformation as ci
    left outer join CustomerMeters as cm on cm.CustomerAddress = ci.Address
    outer apply (
        select
            case
                when cm.ID is not null then 'Number of records in both tabless'
                else 'not in CustomerMeters'
            end as grp
    ) as C
group by C.grp
```

or

```
--number of records in both tables
select count(*)
from CustomerInformation as ci
where ci.Address in (select cm.CustomerAddress from CustomerMeters as cm)

--number of records in CustomerInformation which are not in CustomerMeters
select count(*)
from CustomerInformation as ci
where ci.Address not in (select cm.CustomerAddress from CustomerMeters as cm)
```

Answer (score 2):

Count of records that resulted from the join:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM CustomerInformation 
JOIN CustomerMeters 
  ON CustomerAddress = Address
```

Number of records *exclusively* in the `CustomerInformation` table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM CustomerInformation AS CI -- Records in CustomerInformation
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *      -- that are not in CustomerMeters
                 FROM CustomerMeters AS CM
                 WHERE CM.Address = CI.CustomerAddress)
```

Answer (score 2):

the followng query will give you the list of all records in the `CustomerInformation` table and a flag column `MATCH` which will contain a 1 if a coresponding record exists in the CustomerMeters table, otherwise a zero.

```
SELECT  CI.ID
        ,Ci.Name
        ,CI.CustomerAddress 
        ,CASE WHEN CM.Address IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS MATCH
FROM    CustomerInformation CI
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        CustomerMeters CM 
ON      CM.Address = CI.CustomerAddress
```

Comment: This is great! May I ask one question about this code? I just want to see where Match = 1, but it is saying Match column does not exist, how would I do that? Thank you.

Comment: If you only eant to see rows that match, then use an `INNER JOIN` instead fo the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`